# Failed to notify 'DBA Team' via email

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I setup a test job to test out my failure notifications and now I'm getting the following error, stating it did not notify my operator via email. The strange thing is I ran the same exact setup script on several other instances and it worked just fine, but is failing on this instance. I checked the properties for SQL Server Agent and the operator itself. I also sent myself a test email from the Management branch's Database Mail and it worked successfully.

> Failed to notify 'DBA Team' via email.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure you've enabled Mail Session in SQL Server Agent.

SQL Server Agent > Properties > Alert System: Check Enable mail profile.

This link should help: 
[Avoiding failed notified operator email errors](http://sqlmag.com/blog/avoiding-failed-notify-operator-email-errors)

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced an issue on several instances that occasionally causes SQL Server Agent to stop processing outgoing mail requests.

See [this Microsoft Connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/775018/notification-alert-system-crash-after-any-unrelated-error-of-ole-db-initialization) which seems to indicate this problem may have been fixed in SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 3 and later..

The simplest mitigation for this problem is to simply restart the SQL Server Agent.  Note, you do *not* need to restart SQL Server itself, *only restart the Agent*.

Doing a [quick search of Microsoft Connect](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mail+site%3Aconnect.microsoft.com+%22failed+to+nofify%22+%22via+email%22&atb=v65-7&ia=web) shows several other potential issues around sending email from the Agent.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on a fresh SQL Server instance, and apart from enable the Mail Session as wjm said, I needed to set Profile I was using as the Default Public Profile:

Management > Database Mail > Configure Database Email > Manage Profile Security > Set 'Yes' in 'Default Profile' on the profile you are using.